# Unable to publish project in release mode in Visual studio VS 2013 professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version, .net-4.6

I am unable to publish my project in release mode in Visual Studio 2013 professional. I have recently changed the .net framework of the project to 4.6 from 4.5 and to simulate the dev environment with Test and production environment, i have uninstalled the .Net Framework 4.5 and 4.5.1 SDK from dev machine and have only 4.6.1 framework installed.

**Note : .Net Framework 4.5 and 4.5.1 Target Packs are available in the machine to be used by Visual studio.**

When i publish the project in release mode gives the following error :

**Task could not find "sgen.exe" using Sdktoolspath "" or the registry key :"HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKS\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the Sdktoolpath is set and the the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolPath and the microsoft Windows SDK is installed.**

Checking the registry entries gives this : 
[image]

My dev machine has .Net Framework 4.6 Target Pack and Runtime framework. I want to publish using this framework only. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Windows SDK 8.1 worked for me -

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk.

Plus you need to have the .net Framework installed which is required by your project.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral